# Skype chat archive - permanently delete

Tags: skype, archiving, chat

I would like to ask if it's possible to delete permanently the Skype chat archive, and if it is possible, then how should I do it?

The `Conversations -> Clear recent...` menu option clears only the recent messages, but clicking again on a contact, and presenting the previous messages, shows the (full) archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows: Click on Tools > Options > IM & SMS and the Clear history button.

OS X: Open Skype -> preferences -> privacy.

Comment: Thanks. Note: on OS X you should open Skpye -> preferences -> privacy.

Comment: You never said you were using OS X :)  Glad it worked.

Comment: Only at work... It's necessary... I consider myself Ubuntu-user, but anyway, thanks for the answer:D I know, it was a really noob question, but I couldn't find it anyway :))